# Why can't I make a char array longer than 61 characters in C, using `section .data:` and `section .text:`?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I'm following this [tutorial](https://littleosbook.github.io/) to make a simple bare bones 32-bit operating system. I have gotten as far as section 4 where i'm writing to the frame buffer. Basically i'm attempting to create my own println function. Here is the code for my function:

```
/** fb_write_cell:
 * Writes a character with the given foreground and background to position i
 * in the framebuffer.
 *
 * @param i The location in the framebuffer
 * @param c The character
 * @param fg The foreground color
 * @param bg The background color
 */
static void fb_write_cell(unsigned int i, char c, unsigned char fg, unsigned bg) {
  fb[i] = c;
  fb[i + 1] = ((fg & 0x0F) << 4) | (bg & 0x0F);
}

/** fb_print:
 * Print a string of text to the framebuffer
 * @param *buf The character array to print
 */
int fb_print(char *str, unsigned int length) {
  unsigned int i = 0, x = 0;

  // print the message to the framebuffer
  for(; i < (2 * length); i+=2) {
    fb_write_cell(i, str[x], FB_BLACK, FB_GREEN);
    x++;
  }
  return 0;
}

/** fb_println:
 * Print a string of text to the framebuffer and move to the next line
 * @param *buf The character array to print
 */
int fb_println(char *str, unsigned int length) {
   fb_print(str, length);

  return 0;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
char array[] = "Hello world!";
fb_println(array, sizeof(array));
```

However if I make the array longer than 61 characters I stop getting any output to the screen. In fact any code after the array creation doesn't get executed. I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with limited RAM in my bare system (maybe only 64 bytes?) but I'm not sure.

My multiboot header and startup code in `loader.s` that calls my *C* entry point `main` is:

```
global loader                   ; the entry symbol for ELF

MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0x1BADB002     ; define the magic number constant
FLAGS        equ 0x0            ; multiboot flags
CHECKSUM     equ -MAGIC_NUMBER  ; calculate the checksum
                                ; (magic number + checksum + flags should equal 0)

KERNEL_STACK_SIZE equ 4096      ; size of stack in bytes

extern sum_of_three             ; the function is defined elsewhere
extern main

section .text:                  ; start of the text (code) section
align 4                         ; the code must be 4 byte aligned
    dd MAGIC_NUMBER             ; write the magic number to the machine code,
    dd FLAGS                    ; the flags,
    dd CHECKSUM                 ; and the checksum

section .bss:
align 4                     ; align at 4 bytes
kernel_stack:               ; label points to beginning of memory
    resb KERNEL_STACK_SIZE  ; reserve stack for the kernel

loader:                                           ; the loader label (defined as entry point in linker script)
    mov eax, 0xCAFEBABE                           ; place the number 0xCAFEBABE in the register eax
    mov esp, kernel_stack + KERNEL_STACK_SIZE     ; point esp to the start of the
                                                  ; stack (end of memory area)
    ;Example of how to call a function and send args
    ;push dword 3                                  ; arg3
    ;push dword 2                                  ; arg2
    ;push dword 1                                  ; arg1
    ;call sum_of_three                             ; call the function, the result will be in EAX


.loop:
    call main
    jmp .loop                   ; loop forever
```

My linker script `link.ld` is:

```
ENTRY(loader)                /* the name of the entry label */

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x00100000;          /* the code should be loaded at 1 MB */

    .text ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.text)             /* all text sections from all files */
    }

    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) : /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.rodata*)          /* all read-only data sections from all files */
    }

    .data ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.data)             /* all data sections from all files */
    }

    .bss ALIGN (0x1000) :    /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(COMMON)            /* all COMMON sections from all files */
        *(.bss)              /* all bss sections from all files */
    }
}
```

My whole source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ckchessmaster/OSDevTutorial).

Comment: This doesn't "make [an] array" or allocate memory at runtime at all.

Comment: Aside: how does`int fb_println` "move to the next line", when all it does is to call `fb_print`?

Comment: @Charles Like I said the code works but only for small array size. I also tried dynamically creating the array at runtime using a loop and then it wouldn't display the message if it got too big but at least it would continue past that line and execute further code. I know normally if you need a specific amount of memory you would call malloc but I didn't need it at least for this example.

Comment: 'limited RAM in my bare system (maybe only 64 bytes?)' - could you explain that further?  Also, I'm no longer clickiing on any user links.  After the recent posting of malicious links I'm closing any links as 'Unclear'.

Comment: @Charles yeah it doesn't go to the next line yet lol that's a whole other issue i'm having. My issue here is just displaying on a single line

Comment: @Martin fair enough, here is my source code without a link: github.com/ckchessmaster/OSDevTutorial The tutorial i'm following is called the little book on OS development it's also on github

Comment: The limited memory is just a guess. I'm running it in a virtual machine with plenty of RAM. But i'm wondering if for some reason my program can only use a small fraction of it. I'm fairly new to memory management at the kernel level trying to learn as much as I can

Comment: What I was trying to point out above is that *there isn't actually any memory management happening in this code*. It's believable that strings that are too long crash the system (after all, you're looping on them and twiddling memory). It's *not* believable that this has anything to do with allocation.

Comment: Might I suggest using qemu's gdb support to step through your code as it executes?

Comment: What's `fb`?  If it's an array then its size matters.  If it's a hardware address, then the hardware characteristics are relevant here.

Comment: @charles yeah the tutorial goes into memory management later so that probably is the issue. I'm surprised the tutorial failed to mention that. I'll have to look into the qemu thing i'm using bochs to run it after I combile everything into a .iso.

Comment: @JohnBollinger fb is the initial locaiton of the framebuffer: static char *fb = (char *) 0x000B8000;

Comment: @ckchessmaster, ...so, assuming that it's hardware interpreting that memory's contents to drive the display, the details of the interface defined for communication with that hardware matter. Overrun the region reserved for the purpose (or fail to honor whatever rules it has regarding padding &c) and we're in undefined behavior.

Comment: Your problem is in `loader.s` . You have a line like this `section .text:` that appears before you define your multiboot header. There is an issue there. The colon `:` on the end is a mistake. It should be `section .text` (without a colon). This may cause your program to not appear as a mulitboot compliant elf executable and this can be influenced by the amount of data in a given section.

Comment: @Charles Yeah so basically the frame buffer is split up into 16bit cells in a 80x25 grid (technically larger as there are 3 pages) this is all according to the tutorial and the OSDev wiki. My code writes one cell at time from an array that I assume (maybe incorrectly) it somewhere else entirely. That being said as you pointed out I don't have any memory management so I don't actually know where the variables I make are getting put in memory.

Comment: On a side note I generally put the multiboot header in its own section and add that section to the linker script show it appears first before even the `.text` section.

Comment: @MichaelPetch What does the bss/text section do? It wasn't very clear in the tutorial

Comment: The BSS section is a special section where all the zero initialized data goes (or data that wasn't declared to have a particular value). It is special in that it doesn't take up space in the ELF file but the ELF loader will zero it out as part of the loading process (The ELF loader in GRUB for example will do that for you). You can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues here are not related to your *C* code but problems in your file `loader.s`. You have problems with the section names having a colon on the end that becomes part of the section name, and you haven't put the code in the executable `.text` section.

These lines have extra colons on the section names:

```
section .text:                  ; start of the text (code) section

section .bss:
```

They should be:

```
section .text                   ; start of the text (code) section

section .bss
```

These extra colons cause things to be placed in unexpected way and could be influenced by the amount of data in a particular section (like strings in your *C* code). This likely caused your `kernel.elf` to not always appear as a Multiboot compatible bootloader.

As well code needs to be placed in the `.text` section. You placed your stack and the code after it in the `.bss` section which is incorrect. To fix this place a section directive above the start of your code like this:

```
section .text
loader:                        ; the loader label (defined as entry point in linker script)
```

You also put your kernel in an infinite loop:

```
.loop:
    call main
    jmp .loop                   ; loop forever
```

You probably meant to put an infinite loop after your kernel is complete:

```
    call main
.loop:
    jmp .loop                   ; loop forever
```

---

### Error in LittleOS Book Tutorial

I noticed that this seems to be a mistake on the part of the author of the tutorial you are using in the section [Compiling the Operating System](https://littleosbook.github.io/#compiling-the-operating-system) as the mistake appears in this code:

> ```
> section .text:                  ; start of the text (code) section
> align 4                         ; the code must be 4 byte aligned
> ```

Someone may wish to raise this issue with the author.